# check whether file in particular directory exists or not in java using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

I have a variable 'chckwav' holding a string value and string value is basically showing the path of file

```
checkwav=path+"/wav/new1.wav";// where path variable is the path of file //
```

and using this variable value I have to check whether file `new1.wav` exist or not in specified path. I used the following syntax separately:

```
-   Files.notExists(checkwav)
```

and

```
!File.Exists(checkwav)
```

but both throw the error.

Comment: What is the error?  Can you post your code?

Comment: read javadoc on java.io.File netbeans is an ide. should be same if you use eclipse or notepad

Comment: this site is not a replacement for reading docs or googling / searching for an answer first [FAQ]

Answer (score 1):

From what you said (without actually saying what the error is by the way) it seems like you are trying to pass a String instance to the Files.exist method, when said method takes a Path instance.

Try this code instead:

```
boolean exists = Files.exists(Paths.get(checkwav));
```

*-Thomas*